# XSLT 2.0 create document for each element

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file:

```
<xml>
    <metadata>  
       <book></book>
       <info></info>
       <name></name>
   </metadata>
   <customer>
       <person name = "p1" book="x"></person>
       <person name = "p2" book="y"></person>
   </customer>
</xml>
```

What I need is to create an output file for each customer, what containts the metadata:

output1:

```
<xml>
   <metadata>   
       <book></book>
       <info></info>
       <name></name>
   </metadata>
   <customer>
       <person name = "p1" book="x"></person>
   </customer>
   </xml>
```

output2:

```
<xml>
   <metadata>   
       <book></book>
       <info></info>
       <name></name>
   </metadata>
   <customer>
       <person name = "p2" book="y"></person>
   </customer>
</xml>
```

what I have so far:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" name="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:variable name="persons" select="/xml/customer/person" />

<xsl:template match="xml">
        <xsl:for-each select="$persons">
            <xsl:variable name="filename"  select="concat('\output\',@name,'.xml')" />
            <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" format="xml">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>    


<xsl:template match="metadata">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="customer">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but with that code I'm able to create a file for each person, but the metadata is not in the file. So within my foreach loop I have to apply-templates for all nodes. Is there a way to "go" to the root node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, when you apply your `xsl:for-each` you're in the scope of a `person` element, if you want to copy the metada, you can't apply templates on '*' (which is what you implicitely did with `<xsl:apply-templates/>`and means 'all child elements').

Second, your templates matching `customer` and `metadata` only copy attribute nodes, not the node itself, then can't work neither. Actually none of them are ever matched because you applied templates from person context, ie on person child (and you have none)...

So, I think this is what you try to achieve (done fully in for-each, but one can use a 'match design' instead) :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" name="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="xml">
            <xsl:for-each select="customer/person">
                <xsl:variable name="filename"  select="concat('\output\',@name,'.xml')" />
                <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" format="xml">
                    <xml>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::xml/metadata"/>
                        <customer>
                             <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                        </customer>
                    </xml>
                </xsl:result-document>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```